# can't post when using ajax in django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

So I've been following this tutorial http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/, and the get method works fine. i.e. I get a popup saying what it should say in the popup. However when I use the post method instead I don't get anything. It appears that the request doesn't even reach my view.

This is what my bit of javascript dealing with this looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#popupbutton").click(function(){
        $.post("/launch_instances", { 
                name: "Monty",
                food: "Spam" 
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        );
     });
 ...................
```

This are the related bit of my template:

```
<center>
   <div id="popupbutton"><input type="submit" value="Launch Instances!" /></div>
</center>
```

And here is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def li_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("post gets to the view")
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = "This is an XHR GET request"
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            message = "This is an XHR POST request"
        else:
            message = "Nothing"
    else:
        message = "No XHR"

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

As you can see the first thing I do when I get to my view is return a HttpResponse, but when I am using post I don't see any popup like I do when I am using get. So my guess is that for some reason the request doesn't even reach the view.

This is what my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^launch_instances/', 'simdata.views.li_view'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
)
```

There have been similar questions around but nothing as bizzare as this. I'm new to django/ajax/jquery so probably missing something very small.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is in your `urls.py`? Maybe the bug is there?

Comment: @CypressFrankenfeld I've added my urls.py :)

Comment: If you're using a modern browser like a recent Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug), you should be able to use the developer tools to figure out what's happening to your request.  For example, in Chrome, you should open the Developer console (Wrench->Tools->Developer Tools) and go to the Network tab before triggering your AJAX call.  You can then see the status code and response content which should help you debug.

Comment: in your jquery post, try "/launch_instances/" instead of "/launch_instances".

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor Thank you for that awesome tool. My status text says '500 internal server error' but i don't have any column called response content

Comment: It also might be useful to add `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` right after your method opener. Then, when you make the AJAX request, you can jump over to the shell and walk through the code step by step and introspect the values of everything. That should give you an idea of what's going wrong where.

Comment: @AmirHBP Glad you find it useful--to see the response content, click on the request name in the left column, and the then the Preview or Response tab on the right.

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor Thanks to that response content tool, I was able to figure out that I didn't have a slash at the end of my url. Again thanks for that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh! Wow. That is such a small bug, it took me a while of staring at your code to spot it. You're requesting `/launch_instances` (notice *without* the trailing slash at the end). When Django encounters this, it automatically redirects the request to `/launch_instances/` (with trailing slash), but through the redirection, the POST data is dropped. Add the trailing slash, and you should be golden.

Comment: yeah you are right. I just realised it after looking at the chrome debugger and was coming here to say that. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 4):

You're likely running into Django's automatic CSRF protection (a common issue for people using Django for AJAX requests the first time).  You might want to look at [the documentation on the topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax), or you can mark your view method with the `@csrf_exempt` decorator (though that will introduce a security issue if that method has side effects or could contain secured data).

Comment: I tried doing what the tutorial said but it didn't get me anywhere. Just now I added these two lines right above my method and rebooted the server but stil nothing :(
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt

Answer (score 0):

After adding {% csrf_token %}, Django creates a hidden item like following:

```
 < input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='S1aE7jMFsF24X84CWKf2GxY1UoLzfpf9' / >
```

So when you post the form using javascript, the hidden csrf_token should be posted as well. Try add this value along with your jquery ajax call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "/some/url/",
        data: {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },
    })
```

and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSRF enabled then simple ajax post do not work. you will have to add the csrf token and set it to the ajax request header.

For Ajax POST request, you have to pass the CSRF token in as POST data with every POST request. For this reason, you must get CSRF token first. Since you have enabled CSRF protection so you will get the token from csrftoken cookie. The CSRF token cookie is named csrftoken by default. Acquiring the token is very straight forward and it can be achieved using the below code snippet.

```
enter code here
function getCSRFCookie()
{
name = 'csrftoken';
var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrf_token = getCSRFCookie();
```